# Get distinct Column1 values which contains all required Column2 values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to extract those Jars which contain both `Bunties` and `Candies`.

```
Row#        Column1           Columm2
---------------------------------------       
1           Jar1              Bunties
2           Jar1              Candies
3           Jar1              Biscuits
4           Jar1              Jellies
5           Jar2              Bunties
6           Jar2              Candies
7           Jar2              Biscuits
8           Jar3              Bunties
9           Jar3              Candies
10          Jar4              Bunties
11          Jar4              Jellies
```

`Jar1,Jar2,Jar3` are the desired output because these are the only jars which contains both `Bunties` and `Candies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` to get the result:

```
select Column1
from dbo.yourtable
where Columm2 in ('Bunties', 'Candies') 
group by Column1
having count(distinct Columm2) = 2;
```

Your `WHERE` clause will include the values that you are looking for, then you `GROUP BY` the `Column1` and count the distinct values in `Columm2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use EXISTS:

```
SELECT Distinct t.Column1
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE t.Columm2 IN ('Bunties', 'Candies')
AND EXISTS(
     SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
     WHERE t2.Column1 = t.Column1
     AND   t2.Columm2 <> t.Columm2
     AND   t2.Columm2 IN ('Bunties', 'Candies')
)
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you its working at my end. @TimSchmelter what will be its performance if data is too much long. Will it effect the over all performance while fetching the data?

Comment: @user3310585: that depends on your indexes. http://sqlserverplanet.com/indexes/sql-server-indexes-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN2 IN ('BUNTIES','CANDIES')
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

Comment: He wants all where  a given `Column1` has **both** not one of both.

Comment: @BernardoLima Your answer is not fulfilling my requirement, it will extract jar4 too because it contains Bunties. But i want to get those jars only which contains both bunties and candies.

Comment: @user3310585, can one jar has multiple entries for column 2? Like, Jar3 has two entries for candies.